# Chromedriver couldn't open chrome browser on AWS EC2

Tags: linux, selenium, google-chrome, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run simple Java code to setup EC2 machine on AWS and its pure purpose is to run selenium.

The same code on my local (MAC) works fine, just by changing the chrome path

I could start chromedriver and google-chrome independently with out issues.

- chromedriver version - 71.0.3578.80
- Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98

Here it is the Java Code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TecAdminSeleniumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

            driver.get("https://google.com");

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            if (driver.getPageSource().contains("I'm Feeling Lucky")) {
                    System.out.println("Pass");
            } else {
                    System.out.println("Fail");
            }
            driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Error observed:

```
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'XXXXXXX', ip: 'XXXXXX', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.77-70.59.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
```

I keep getting the following exception :

```
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startSession(ChromeDriver.java:182)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:161)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:150)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:139)
```

Comment: What is the exception message? The stack trace is there, it obviously can't start the driver, but what is the exception itself?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15' System info: host: 'XXXXXXX', ip: 'XXXXXX', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.77-70.59.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
```

...implies that there are some **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **2.39.0** of **2013-12-16 16:11:15** which is more than **5 years** older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_25** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u25* and *Selenium Client v2.39*

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u191**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.45**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v70-72*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.